# Strange Compilation Error

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, compilation, anaconda

I am having this error when using gcc 7.3. It appears for the gcc 7.3 comes from Ubuntu 18.04 and gcc 7.3 compiled on RedHat 6.9. But it disappears for gcc 4.8.5 from Anaconda2.

I understand that without source code, it will be very difficult for people to help. But I don't have the permission to post all of them. I will appreciate any advice that helps me identify why the different behaviors between gcc 7.3 and 4.8.5. .

The program is built by Scons, which I am not familiar with. I am happy to provide more info but I don't know how.

The error is:

```
 [ TRACING]  -> X86/debug/DiskImageWrite.hh
 [SO PARAM] CowDiskImage -> X86/params/CowDiskImage.hh
 [SO PARAM] DiskImage -> X86/params/DiskImage.hh
 [SO PARAM] RawDiskImage -> X86/params/RawDiskImage.hh
 [     CXX] X86/dev/disk_image.cc -> .o
build/X86/dev/copy_engine.cc: In member function 'void CopyEngine::CopyEngineChannel::channelRead(Packet*, Addr, int)':
build/X86/dev/copy_engine.cc:249:43: error: '~' on an expression of type bool [-Werror=bool-operation]
         pkt->set<uint64_t>(cr.status() | ~busy);
                                           ^~~~
build/X86/dev/copy_engine.cc:249:43: note: did you mean to use logical not ('!')?
```

I can tell that it is not C syntax by "~" and very likely a Python code. But why does it work for Anaconda gcc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` is the [bitwise negation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) in C and C++.

The source file, `X86/dev/disk_image.cc`, in which the diagnostic is raised
is a C++ source file that is being compiled as such (`[     CXX]`).

`~` is not a boolean operation. Applying `~` to a `bool` expression, as evidently happens in `~busy`, is probably a
mistake on the programmer's part, which may or may not actually be harmful in the program. As gcc 7.3 suggests, they probably intended logical
negation, `!busy`.

`gcc 7.3` diagnoses this probable mistake with a warning when diagnostic option `-Wall` is
in effect, and with the addition of option `-Werror` ( = treat warnings as errors),
the diagnostic becomes an error. [See here](https://godbolt.org/g/2GkFp1)

The much older `gcc 4.8.5` does not diagnose this probable mistake (with the same diagnostic options,
or any others). [See here](https://godbolt.org/g/iEiCcq)

This difference is what you are observing.